# Automated video call between two bots

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to write a script to run an automated video call between two bots, where instead of streaming video from a camera, they stream a video from a file.

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is you knowledge about writing bots? If this is not know then it is a difficult question to answer. Add info to your question about where you got stuck. If is is creating a bot, than read [this1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-bot), or [this2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams))

Comment: So currently this is what I got:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/automated-video-call-between-two-bots/m-p/1985329/highlight/false#M2317
Thanks!